# What could turn on the TCP Keep-Alive flag? Is my traffic being corrupted?

Tags: networking, tcp, virtualbox, epoll

#### Background

I'm stress testing my client-server application. Both ends are C++ programs with event detection via `epoll`.

In this test they are each running on CentOS 7 in an Oracle VirtualBox 5.0.22 instance, communicating over VirtualBox's Host-Only Ethernet Adaptor (type: *Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82504EM)*).

The client opens a TCP/IP connection to the server, exchanges some application-level handshake messages, and maintains it by pumping through a single ASCII 20 (whitespace) every ten seconds. Call this a "ping". After a certain number of expected "pings" have been missed by either side, the connection is closed.

Under some circumstances, the server can also open a connection to the client to re-establish communication faster (e.g. after the server has restarted). In most configurations, the client will actually end up re-opening its own outgoing connection too and the server's connection will be closed as "redundant".

This is working okay at small scales, but when I try to simulate there being many clients on a network, [things fall apart](http://westwing.wikia.com/wiki/Things_Fall_Apart). Since the server needs each client to be on a distinct IP, for the simulation I create some "virtual interfaces" in 192.168.21.0/24, and play with routing.

Say I'm simulating 20 clients. To set up the 12th, I'll execute this on my client VM:

```
ip link add link enp0s8 sbsim12 type macvlan
ip link set up dev sbsim12
ip addr add 192.168.21.12/24 broadcast 192.168.21.255 dev sbsim12
```

<sup>(enp0s8 is the VirtualBox Host-Only Adaptor)</sup>

Then, on the server VM:

```
ip route add 192.168.21.0/24 dev enp0s8
```

An instance of my client can then bind to 192.168.21.12 and, henceforth, in my system, that appears to be its IP.

#### Problem

This mechanism worked rather well for us when our application used UDP comms. It also works fine at small scales. However, when I start up more and more clients at a time, I start to see strange behaviour. Symptoms vary, but the general pattern appears to be the TCP/IP connection stalling. With masses of debug output in my application, I can see that the sending side is correctly detecting `EPOLLOUT` on the socket and `send`ing to it, but the receiving side occasionally never detects `EPOLLIN` so data effectively goes missing. This occurs every few runs, with increasing probability as the number of clients grows.

Having spent what feels like a decade forensically analysing the correctness of my application's logic, I'm starting to wonder whether I'm hitting some kind of networking bug at a lower layer, either within the MAC VLAN realm or the VirtualBox driver realm.

In order to rule that out, I need somebody with a much better understanding of TCP than I have, to confirm or deny that the following is really weird.

What on earth is going on in this packet stream?

[image: Screenshot of packet capture in Wireshark around the time it all goes wrong]

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Info
  26496 581.345275     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=377482702 TSecr=0 WS=128
  26499 581.345711     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381905815 TSecr=377482702 WS=128
  26500 581.345936     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0 TSval=377482703 TSecr=381905815
  26516 581.349421     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=131 TSval=381905865 TSecr=377482703
  26519 581.349661     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=132 Win=30336 Len=0 TSval=377482706 TSecr=381905865
  26647 581.394528     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=132 Win=30336 Len=131 TSval=377482751 TSecr=381905865
  26648 581.394574     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=132 Ack=132 Win=30336 Len=0 TSval=381905911 TSecr=377482751
  26690 581.401738     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=132 Ack=132 Win=30336 Len=289 TSval=377482758 TSecr=381905911
  26691 581.401756     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=132 Ack=421 Win=31360 Len=0 TSval=381905918 TSecr=377482758
  26735 581.418696     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=132 Ack=421 Win=31360 Len=48 TSval=381905935 TSecr=377482758
  26737 581.418927     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [ACK] Seq=421 Ack=180 Win=30336 Len=0 TSval=377482776 TSecr=381905935
  26749 581.432843     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=180 Ack=421 Win=31360 Len=45 TSval=381905949 TSecr=377482776
  26751 581.433022     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [ACK] Seq=421 Ack=225 Win=30336 Len=0 TSval=377482790 TSecr=381905949
  26758 581.436982     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=421 Ack=225 Win=30336 Len=819 TSval=377482793 TSecr=381905949
  26793 581.476317     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=225 Ack=1240 Win=33024 Len=0 TSval=381905993 TSecr=377482793
  26892 581.579434     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=225 Ack=1240 Win=33024 Len=64 TSval=381906096 TSecr=377482793
  26950 581.619040     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [ACK] Seq=1240 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=0 TSval=377482976 TSecr=381906096
  27012 581.652478     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=1240 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1230 TSval=377483007 TSecr=381906096
  27013 581.652520     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2470 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381906168 TSecr=377483007
  28392 590.844958     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2470 Win=35968 Len=1 TSval=381915361 TSecr=377483007
  28427 590.955619     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1 TSval=377492312 TSecr=381906168
  28428 590.955628     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=290 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381915472 TSecr=377492312
  28457 591.077735     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=1 TSval=381915594 TSecr=377492312
  28494 591.161676     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1 TSval=377492518 TSecr=381906168
  28495 591.161733     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=290 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381915678 TSecr=377492518 SLE=2470 SRE=2471
  28526 591.367239     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1 TSval=377492724 TSecr=381906168
  28527 591.367344     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=290 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381915883 TSecr=377492724 SLE=2470 SRE=2471
  28566 591.776390     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=1 TSval=381916293 TSecr=377492724
  28567 591.780375     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1 TSval=377493137 TSecr=381906168
  28568 591.780472     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=290 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381916297 TSecr=377493137 SLE=2470 SRE=2471
  28601 592.243918     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=1 TSval=381916760 TSecr=377493137
  28639 592.607472     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1 TSval=377493964 TSecr=381906168
  28640 592.607575     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=290 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381917124 TSecr=377493964 SLE=2470 SRE=2471
  28729 593.177610     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=1 TSval=381917694 TSecr=377493964
  28826 594.259300     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1 TSval=377495616 TSecr=381906168
  28827 594.259358     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=290 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381918776 TSecr=377495616 SLE=2470 SRE=2471
  28863 595.043696     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=1 TSval=381919560 TSecr=377495616
  29669 597.563164     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1 TSval=377498920 TSecr=381906168
  29670 597.563296     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=290 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381922079 TSecr=377498920 SLE=2470 SRE=2471
  30012 598.779594     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=1 TSval=381923296 TSecr=377498920
  30485 604.179630     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] 42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1 TSval=377505536 TSecr=381906168
  30486 604.179745     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive ACK] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=290 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381928696 TSecr=377505536 SLE=2470 SRE=2471
  30679 606.251285     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Keep-Alive] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2471 Win=35968 Len=1 TSval=381930768 TSecr=377505536
  30824 610.881089     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=2471 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=1 TSval=377512238 TSecr=381906168
  30825 610.881786     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      45431→cisco-sccp(2000) [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=377512238 TSecr=0 WS=128
  30826 610.881829     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381935398 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  30858 610.885132     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=290 Ack=2473 Win=35968 Len=1 TSval=381935401 TSecr=377512238
  30937 611.883833     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 45431→cisco-sccp(2000) [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=377513240 TSecr=0 WS=128
  30938 611.884005     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381936400 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  30973 612.884024     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381937400 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  30996 613.887453     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 45431→cisco-sccp(2000) [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=377515244 TSecr=0 WS=128
  30997 613.887564     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381938404 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  31123 616.083906     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381940600 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  31195 617.395119     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=2 TSval=377518752 TSecr=381906168
  31196 617.395213     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 30858#1] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=292 Ack=2473 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381941911 TSecr=377518752 SLE=2470 SRE=2473
  31197 617.891274     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 45431→cisco-sccp(2000) [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=377519248 TSecr=0 WS=128
  31198 617.891377     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381942407 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  31358 621.211512     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2473 Win=35968 Len=2 TSval=381945728 TSecr=377518752
  31392 622.484650     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381947001 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  31465 625.907246     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 45431→cisco-sccp(2000) [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=377527264 TSecr=0 WS=128
  31466 625.907346     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381950423 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  31847 634.085643     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381958602 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  32326 641.938500     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 45431→cisco-sccp(2000) [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=377543296 TSecr=0 WS=128
  32327 641.938568     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381966455 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  32458 643.859279     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 42551→cisco-sccp(2000) [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=2470 Ack=289 Win=30336 Len=2 TSval=377545216 TSecr=381906168
  32459 643.859394     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Dup ACK 30858#2] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [ACK] Seq=292 Ack=2473 Win=35968 Len=0 TSval=381968375 TSecr=377545216 SLE=2470 SRE=2473
  32861 651.099614     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→42551 [FIN, PSH, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=2473 Win=35968 Len=2 TSval=381975616 TSecr=377545216
  33374 658.088603     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      [TCP Retransmission] cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28960 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=381982605 TSecr=377512238 WS=128
  34426 674.002725     192.168.21.51         192.168.99.100        TCP      [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 45431→cisco-sccp(2000) [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=377575360 TSecr=0 WS=128
  34433 674.004602     192.168.99.100        192.168.21.51         TCP      cisco-sccp(2000)→45431 [RST, ACK] Seq=668009898 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

Comment: It's almost never a bug in the lower layers. I would check if epoll is used correctly, as that API is very tricky (why aren't you using llibevent/libev/libuv instead?). I would also look at all those retransmissions, maybe there is packet loss.

Comment: @o9000: In the virtualisation world it's not uncommon. And I'm now quite confident that `epoll` is used correctly. I'm isolating the problem codewise at the moment but I wanted someone to confirm my suspicions, that some of the SEQ and ACK numbers in the above don't make sense, and that the Keep-Alive flag shouldn't be coming on all by itself.

Comment: If the TCP stream actually looks fine (I am not a network engineer :P) then I can refocus my efforts.

Comment: "the server can also open a connection to the client" - You mean client too has a port open for `listen` and roles change?

Comment: The keep-alive should start atleast a second after the idleness of the line. Your tcpdump indicate keep-alive starting within a second after last "ping" was out on the line.. Can you undo keep-alive setting from application altogether and try?

Comment: I checked the sequence numbers of the first flow and they look OK. Perfectly normal. Wireshark shows them in red just because the seq number goes back by 1, but that's how keepalive works, it retransmits the last byte. However the second flow, the one from port 45431, is not OK. We can see the client sending the SYN over and over again (hence the subsequent packets are marked as spurious retransmissions); the server replies with SYN-ACK but the client doesn't seem to react to it. I think this is likely your problem.

Comment: Next time try to filter by TCP flow, it's hard to read the log with packets from 2 flows interleaved.

Comment: Did you clone the virtual machines by any chance? Are you sure they have different MAC addresses and IP addresses? Does the problem get resolved if you use a different kind of adapter (I would try the physical one, even if it means moving the server to a different host)?

Comment: @Prabhu: _"Can you undo keep-alive setting from application altogether and try?"_ The application isn't setting it in the first place.

Comment: @o9000: _"the server replies with SYN-ACK but the client doesn't seem to react to it. I think this is likely your problem"_ Is this how SYN cookies work? I've been reading about them.

Comment: @o9000: _"Did you clone the virtual machines by any chance?"_ No. _"Are you sure they have different MAC addresses and IP addresses?"_ Yes. _"Does the problem get resolved if you use a different kind of adapter (I would try the physical one, even if it means moving the server to a different host)?"_ No. In fact I took the clients off the VM and ran them from physical hardware, and I got the same result. Current working theory is that I'm basically beating the cr@p out of macvlan. Tomorrow I try to reproduce without it (but this isn't trivial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone I've spoken to agrees that there is "weirdness" in the TCP interactions.

I rewrote my application so that it could talk to multiple simulated clients at the same IP but different ports, and the problem entirely vanished.

So, either macvlan in kernel 3.10.0 is not fit for use in this manner, or I set it up incorrectly. Or both.